# How to open a new browser window after clicking on a link in rich text box(C#)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, url, richtextbox

i have a twitter application that retrieves user timeline and appends it to a rich text box. However when i click the links nothing happens ?

What's wrong here doesn't rich text box automatically handles the creation of new broswer windows with the specified link. If not then how can i implement such functionality ?

and i am using winforms.

Comment: read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f591a55w.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First You have set **DetectUrls property** set to ***True***

Then

```
RichTextBox1_LinkClicked(System.Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.LinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(e.LinkText);
    //open link with default application
}
```

Also see [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-HK/vbpowerpacks/thread/b9433f73-43a9-4f09-aa8b-0d4204b2a9b0) link for more.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

```
Process.Start("http://www.example.com/");
```

This will open the link in the users default browser.